# In the Bills and Adjustment screen I need to set Project and Task to be conditionally enabled

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization to the Bills and Adjustments screen where I need the Project and Task in the grid section to be enabled beyond what is specified in the source code.

In order to do this, I've used an overridden RowSelected event, but this doesn't seem to work.  The additional context here is that the Approval Map settings come into play.

Here is the code to override the RowSelected event that I thought would work but doesn't:

```
    protected void APInvoice_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
        if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
            InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);

        var apinv = (APInvoice)e.Row;

        if (apinv != null)
        {

            APRegister apreg = PXSelect<APRegister, Where<APRegister.refNbr, Equal<Required<APRegister.refNbr>>>>.Select(Base, apinv.RefNbr);

            if (apreg.Released != true)
            {

                PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APTran.projectID>(Base.Transactions.Cache, null, true);
                PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APTran.taskID>(Base.Transactions.Cache, null, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone explain why this doesn't enable these fields?  Is there another way to do this (short of completely replicating the RowSelected event in the source code)?

Thanks much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Acumatica support:

"I've tested this on 20R102 and 20R109.
It only worked on the later which means that this is most likely a bug.

I will check this with engineering but I am aware of some APInvoice bugs that were solved starting 20R104."

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the cache you're referring to is in the same 'state'(for a lack of a better word). try swaping out Base.tran.... with the PXCache that you are receiving "cache"

```
 protected void APInvoice_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
        try
           {
                if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
                InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
                PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APTran.projectID>(cache, null, true);
                PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APTran.taskID>(cache, null, true);
           }
    catch(System.Exception) {}
    }
```

Comment: Nah - that doesn't do it.  I had tried that before.  Thanks, though...

Comment: I am guessing this code will only work after the apreg is created.  I have updated my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, that overrides the base event and everything ends up being enabled.  What I want to do is let the base event run (which disables all those things that need to be disabled in that screen - such as VendID), but then after that enable only those specific fields.  If I add the 'InvokeBaseHandler', then the custom code to enable those fields doesn't seem to work...

Comment: true, adding that back. I usually extend my functions not overwrite.

Comment: Nah - still doesn't enable the Project and Task fields.  They stay disabled.